# QTP/UFT automation from Citrix server of local applications

Tags: automation, qtp, citrix, hp-uft

I have UFT 11.5 installed on Citrix Server, and trying to use the same to automate local desktop application. But QTP/UFT is not able to recognize the local desktop window, hence not able to proceed.

Please help and provide any suggestion that can be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UFT has to be installed on the same computer of the application you want to test.  When you run UFT through Citrix, you're just seeing the UI of the UFT application replicated in a local window, but all the logic is still isolated to the Citrix server.  That means it only "sees" other applications running on the server, not your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

Citrix applications are streamed to the client computers as images (works in the same way as remote desktop). For this reason accessing the UI elements tree is not possible, and normal UI automation does not work.

Installing automation tools on the Citrix server does the trick.

If this is not possible try [UiPath](http://uipath.com/automate/citrix-automation). It is a GUI automation tool that makes [Citrix automation](http://www.uipath.com/automate/citrix-automation) very handy.  It works also with desktop, web, java, wpf, etc.

[Here's a tutorial](http://pages.uipath.com/tutorials/citrix-automation-data-entry) showing different Citrix (or virtual desktops) automation techniques for

- [automating data entry on Citrix](http://pages.uipath.com/tutorials/citrix-automation-data-entry)
- [OCR data scraping](http://pages.uipath.com/tutorials/citrix-automation-ocr-data-extraction)
- [clicking and typing relative to an image or text](http://pages.uipath.com/tutorials/citrix-automation-click-scraped-text)

You can create visual automation or workflows (see the image) or use it from code via an SDK.

[image]

**Note:** I work at UiPath. You should also try other visual automation tools like Automation Anywhere, WinAutomation, Jacada, use them side by side and choose the one that suits better your needs.